# Using Python's xlrd module to find column with most dates

Tags: python, excel, date, datetime, xlrd

New to Python (and StackOverflow!), any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to loop through columns in an excel spreadsheet, and identify which column contains the highest number of date entries.

The problem seems to be with formatting inside the Excel spreadsheet. The dates in my excel file are listed as yyyy-mm-dd, but the module seems to be interpreting them as integers, e.g. 2012-10-12 = 1990. Similarly, a date 3/1/2014 is being interpreted as 3 divided by 1 divided by 2014 = 0.00149.

Up until now I've been using the xlrd module in Python to count the number of dates in a specific column. I've tried with .xls and .xlsx, and have also tried formatting_info=True with no success.

Here is the code of a function I've tried to use...

```
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlrd import XL_CELL_DATE

def find_maturity_date_column2(file, threshold):

    wb = open_workbook(file)

    sheet_index = 0

    max_sheet_score = 0
    max_col_score = 0

    maturity_sheet_index = 0
    maturity_col_index = 0

    for a in wb.sheets():
        current_sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(sheet_index)
        sheet_score = 0
        for column in range(0,a.ncols):
            col_score = 0
            for row in range(0,a.nrows):
                if current_sheet.cell(row,column).ctype == xlrd.XL_CELL_DATE:
                    sheet_score = sheet_score + 1
                    col_score = col_score + 1
                else:
                    sheet_score = sheet_score
                    col_score = col_score

            if sheet_score >= max_sheet_score and col_score > max_col_score:
                max_col_score = col_score
                max_sheet_score = sheet_score
                maturity_sheet_index = sheet_index
                maturity_col_index = column
            else:
                max_col_score = max_col_score
                max_sheet_score = max_sheet_score
                maturity_sheet_index = maturity_sheet_index
                maturity_col_index = maturity_col_index            
        sheet_index = sheet_index + 1

    if max_col_score < threshold:
        maturity_sheet_index = "None Found"
        maturity_col_index = "None Found"
    else:
        maturity_sheet_index = maturity_sheet_index
        maturity_col_index = maturity_col_index

    return maturity_sheet_index, maturity_col_index
```

This code isn't generating any success. Any ideas on how I could fix this? Maybe there is a different way apart from xlrd?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Here is an example of the file input...(in csv format)

```
Tranche,Maturity Date,Country,Currency,Initial Spread
Term Loan B,2020-10-12,USA,USD,0.025
Term Loan B,2020-11-02,USA,USD,0.0275
Term Loan B,2020-05-22,USA,USD,0.0275
```

How do I build a process that will identify that column = 1 is the column with the highest number of dates (when the module interprets column 1 values to be integers instead of dates)

Comment: you could try converting to datetime object and then comparing

Comment: Sorry of this is a silly question, but if you have a variable being interpreted as an integer, e.g. value = 2012-12-10 = 1990, how do you convert to a datetime object?

Comment: are you having an issue writing or just counting the dates?

Comment: Just counting the dates - my goal is to identify which column in the spreadsheet contains the highest number of dates.

Comment: are there other values other than dates?

Comment: Yes, the spreadsheet will contain various columns of differing data formats. But the date column will only contain dates and blank cells

Comment: what formats are your dates in?

Comment: Different spreadsheets will have different formats. The tool should scan through any spreadsheet and identify any date values...

Comment: do you want to post a small example of your input and I will try running your code or  add a link to one of the files

Comment: I can give you a way to do it using the csv lib if that is any good

Comment: Any ideas are welcome...pls post as an answer below...thanks!

Comment: are all header the same Maturity date etc..?

Comment: No, every spreadsheet will have different headers, some might not have headers.

Comment: how do you know where the dates are?

Comment: You don't know where the dates are. That's the whole point of my question. You have to loop through columns and rows and identify which column contain the largest number of dates.

Comment: that would be easy if you had  headers but not so without, I still think your best bet is trying to parse the times as datetime objects, and do a count of the successful ones, are you counting the highest in each file where a file can have dates in multiple columns or does each file just have one date column?

Comment: Instead of testing for `date` type, I would look for a match with the pattern of a date-formatted string, like `r'(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)'` and count those.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing looking at the type of the cell before deciding whether it is a date-time

```
 if current_sheet.cell(row,column) == xlrd.XL_CELL_DATE:
```

should be changed to

```
 if current_sheet.cell(row,column).ctype == xlrd.XL_CELL_DATE:
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I did actually include the .ctype field in my original code (copied the wrong batch of code above), and it still isn't working...I've edited my initial question with the .ctype added.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, the cell isn't formatted as a date, which is why xlrd isn't detecting that a date is being used (it interprets the field as a formula with an integer output)

Answer (score 1):

I have to break Stack Overflow protocol here and provide an "answer" even though what this question really needs is sharper comments and edits (or perhaps better still, a chat room).  The existing train of comments is way too long already.

The suspicion that the "dates" in the file are not being detected as dates by xlrd due to being improperly formatted (that is, they're *not* dates, in any Excel sense) is a good one. So the question remains: What are they?

We can go about this from at least two angles: report what xlrd is telling us, or report what Excel is telling us. (Yes, there are other things we can do, but honestly, xlrd is an extremely competent Excel-reader, and we shouldn't have to use anything else.)

Now, I know for sure that xlrd is NOT interpreting any cell as "a formula with an integer output". xlrd doesn't know or care about formulas, and from a data storage point of view, there is no such thing as an Excel integer. (Every number in Excel is a float. Some may happen to have values that *compare* equal to an integer. But their data type is float. This includes anything that Excel might consider a date.)

So, on the Excel side: What does the cell *look* like? A screenshot is a better supporting document than a CSV, because a lot of information is lost when writing to CSV (to the point that loading the CSV back into Excel very often gives you something different than what you started with). What is the format string of the cell? (From Excel, navigate the menus as if you are going to manually change the formatting, choose the Custom option, and it should display the existing format string, which could be something like `0.00` or `#,##0.00` or `m/d/yyyy` or `@`, etc.)

From the xlrd side, what are the `ctype` and `value` of the cell in question? Instead of just printing the value, print the representation, using the `repr` function. For example,

```
print current_sheet.cell(row,column).ctype
print repr(current_sheet.cell(row,column).value)
```

Provide this information (either edit your question or comment on this answer), and maybe we'll make some progress.

Incidentally, your code is definitely not as concise as it could be. There are plenty of lines that don't really do anything at all. I get it, you're still new, and that's fine. Despite all that, the code does seem to work on the CSV data that was given (because if you load that CSV into Excel, it will interpret the date-looking things as dates).

Comment: Thanks for your comments here. Appreciated.